# Compare two tables with different schema in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in different databases with different schema, how can I compare them both?

Let's say I have the `DB1` with the table `history.Table1` and another `DB2` with the same table but in a different schema, `backup.Table1`.

Now I need to compare what's different besides the schema name obviously.

Comment: You could simply script the objects to a text file and compare using any text file compare tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SQL Compare from Redgate. They allow you to compare pretty much everything from the actual data to the schema.

I dont believe there is any native functionality in sqlserver.

[Compare SQL Server schemas and deploy differences fast](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/)

[Compare and deploy SQL Server database contents](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)

Comment: Its pretty much the go to for sqlserver comparing.The only downfall is it is expensive. However they allow a month trial.